# Pointers keeping information throughout function calls

Tags: c

I am a bit confused by what is happening with my pointers between function calls.  It is not what I would expect.  I have the following situation:

```
SomeClass *p1= 0, *p2 = 0;
SomeMethod(p1, p2);
printf("P1 total: %d\n", p1->total); // crashes
printf("P2 total: %d\n", p2->total); // crashes

// method someMethod, where the values of the pointers are valid
void SomeMethod(SomeClass *p1, SomeClass *p2)
{
    someMethodThatModifiesThePointers(&p1, &p2);
    printf("P1 total: %d\n", p1->total); // prints valid value
    printf("P2 total: %d\n", p2->total); // prints valid value
};
```

As you can see from my comments, the pointer's .total property (an integer) is valid inside of the method, but is no longer valid outside of it.  Why is this the case?  The pointers shouldn't be losing scope.

To be exact, `someMethodThatModifiesThePointers()` is opencv's `cvExtractSURF`.  I pulled away code to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is a pass-by-value language.  That means that the pointers in your original function *cannot* be changed by the call to `SomeMethod()` (C doesn't have methods, by the way).  You're crashing on the commented lines because `p1` and `p2` are still null pointers at that time.

The same goes for the pointers *inside* `SomeMethod()`.  Your lines comented `prints valid value` will crash for the same reason if you pass null pointers to `SomeMethod()`.  It's impossible for you to be getting the output you say you are, at least given the code you've shown.  If you made a mistake in your example, and you meant this line to be:

```
    someMethodThatModifiesThePointers(&p1, &p2);
```

It could be working the way you explain - `p1` and `p2` are then being passed by reference (that is, you are passing a pointer-to-a-pointer by value), and their values could be valid inside `SomeMethod()`.  The original copies of `p1` and `p2` in your code up top there would still be null pointers, however.

You can fix your problem by doing the same - pass `p1` and `p2` to `SomeMethod()` by reference:

```
 SomeMethod(&p1, &p2);
```

That change will require you to make some modifications in `SomeMethod()`:

```
void SomeMethod(SomeClass **p1, SomeClass **p2)
{
    someMethodThatModifiesThePointers(p1, p2);
    printf("P1 total: %d\n", (*p1)->total);
    printf("P2 total: %d\n", (*p2)->total);
};
```

After this call, `p1` and `p2` in your top function will behave the way you want them to.

Comment: Note that you can/must emulate pass-by-reference by another pointer (i.e. `SomeClass **` parameters, passing `&p1` to `SomeMethod`, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I made a small typo in my original code but I don't think it'll change anything.  Just added & in front of the parameters in the function calls.  someMethodThatModifiesThePointers is cvExtractSURF, which actually allocates and fills the pointers (it gathers SURF points from an image and fills the pointers with the SURF points).

Comment: @vapo, that's what I thought.  The same explanations in my answer still apply.

Comment: Ahhh I understand.  So, If I want the values to be valid on the outside, should I pass a pointer to the pointer as the parameter to someMethod, and then call someMEthodThatModifiesThePointers(p1,p2);?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is...

**You**: create a pointer to an 'instance' of SomeClass.

**GCC**: no problem! done.

**You**: assign 0x0 as the value for that pointer. That is, the 'object' it points to is located in memory in position 0x0

**GCC**: allright, 0x0 does not belong to your program, but I'll roll with it.

**You**: okay. Next, do something with my brand new SomeClass instance! Compile and run!

**Operating System**: WOAH WOAH wait a second, buster. You should've thought about using `malloc()` to ask me for some memory first. That 0x0 memory position belongs to ME, not to you. General Protection Fault, amigo, enjoy crashing.

(By the way, the terms 'class', 'instance', etc. are Object-Oriented Programming terms, they don't quite belong in C. We usually talk about structures, functions and pointers here :)

Comment: LOL I Wish GCC and the OS would talk to me like that.

Comment: My apologies and thanks for the explanation.  I made a slight typo in my code posted above.  Mainly, the parameters passed to someMethodThatModifiesThePointers

Answer (score 0):

> the pointer's .total property (an integer) is valid inside of the method, but is no longer valid outside of it. Why is this the case?

Given the fact it prints valid value inside `SomeMethod` prints valid value and crashes up on return of the `SomeMethod`,I guess that both `p1,p2` are **passed by value**. Upon return of `SomeMethod`, both `p1,p2` are **null pointers** and dereferencing it explains the crash. You need to post the code of `someMethodThatModifiesThePointers(p1, p2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion is that you have chosen the same names for the pointers outside and inside the function. Try this instead:

```
SomeClass *p1= 0, *p2 = 0;
SomeMethod(p1, p2);
printf("P1 total: %d\n", p1->total); // crashes
printf("P2 total: %d\n", p2->total); // crashes

// method someMethod, where the values of the pointers are valid
void SomeMethod(SomeClass *p3, SomeClass *p4)
{
    someMethodThatModifiesThePointers(&p3, &p4);
    printf("P3 total: %d\n", p3->total); // prints valid value
    printf("P4 total: %d\n", p4->total); // prints valid value
};
```

The pointers p1 and p2 are copied to p3 and p4 respectively, but not the other way round.